# Rolling around to update existing record in mongodb using mongotemplate

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

For me i want to update the existing record in mongodb using spring mongotemplate.For that i have to search the existing record from the mongodb.While saving record in mongodb it automatically creates field called `"_id"` in each and every record. I tried a lot to access this field.But i can't able to do.. :(

So that i manually created one field called `myid` in my DTO object. Each and every time saving i'm serializing the id in file and saving.Searching using this `myid`.I know hard code file path will create problem while deploying in server.

Is there any way to do this or any way to access system generated `_id` for searching and updating .. ??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`_id` is a primary key. If you don't specify a field in your object with annotation `@id` then `Mongo` will create one for you. You cannot access it because `Mongo` is not able to populate that field as it does not exists or there is a mapping missing.

You will have to have something like in your code [It would be nice if you could post you code too.]

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

@Id
protected String id;
```

HTH

Comment: Is it mandatory to us @Id field to make update work in mongodb?